# The program stops and don't excute the Threads Why?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I wrote a program which takes number of numbers from the user and then allow to enter the numbers , then create two threads one to calculate the sum and the other to calculate the Avg
but after giving the numbers the program stops and gives error Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int count ;

DWORD WINAPI Sum(PVOID s)
{
    int *sum=(int *)s;
    DWORD c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        c+=sum[i];
    return c;
}

DWORD WINAPI Avg(PVOID s)
{
    int *var=(int *)s;
    DWORD avg=0;
    avg=(*var/count);
    return avg; 
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&count);
    int *s = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
    printf("now enter the numbers\n");
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        scanf("%d",s[i]);

    HANDLE t1 , t2;
    DWORD id1 , id2 , c1 , c2;
    t1 = CreateThread(NULL , 0 , Sum , s , 0 , &id1);
    WaitForSingleObject(t1,INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(t1 , &c1);
    printf("The Sum = %d", c1);
    t2 = CreateThread(NULL , 0 , Avg , (PVOID*)&c1 , 0 , &id2);
    WaitForSingleObject(t2,INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(t2 , &c2);
    printf("The AVgerage = %d", c2);
    return 0;
}
```

If any one would help me  will be Thanksfull.
Thanks
So T update the program and now it's work but the Avg is wrong and that's because when I try to print it like this printf("The AVG=%f\n",c2) the result is zero  Why?

Comment: Please add a language tag to this question.  I assume C++?

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` needs references.

```
scanf("%d",&s[i]);
```

Comment: I put it but still the same .

Comment: You'll have the honor to find the rest of the problems yourself :)

Comment: I'll have that honor later , because I have an exam after 12 hours , so I need to know.

Comment: @Lara: With that attitude you'll surely be exercising that honour on your own ;)